# Do Linux raw sockets receive forwarded traffic?

Tags: linux, raw-sockets

Do Linux raw sockets receive:

1. traffic destined for one of the box's local interfaces
2. outbound traffic from one the box's local interfaces
3. forwarded traffic (neither from, or to, the local interfaces)

Comment: What have you tried already to figure this out? Can you come up with some test?